# Symfony: FOSRESTBundle and JMSSerializerBundle, how to exclude a property on listing

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have a rest api on a symfony project using FOSRest and JMSSerializer.

I want to exclude one of the properties of the objects in the cgetObjectAction (api/my-objects) method but leave it on the single get endpoint (api/my-objects/1).

I've been reading and I came accross the possibility to use groups for the JMS Serializer https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations (I'm already familiar with the possibility of excluding/exposing a var in every method)

But my question is, how can I specify in the cgetObjectAction method to use the group I define (i.e. collection and single).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2, FOSRestBundle. How to use group with JMSSerializerBundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437023/symfony2-fosrestbundle-how-to-use-group-with-jmsserializerbundle)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but in case someone needs an answer, here is some help.

To specify the group you want to use, you need to add this in the View annotation of your controller :

```
@JMS\View(serializerGroups={"YOUR_GROUP_NAME"})
```

And don't forget to add the use statement :

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as JMS;
```