# JMS Serializer Error: Call to a member function getUser() on null

Tags: symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.2

I want to serialize a object in Symfony 3. So I wrote this code:

```
$serializer = $this->getContainer()->get('jms_serializer');
$context = SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks()->setGroups([...]);
$jsonObject = $serializer->serialize($object, 'json', $context);
```

The object is of the class `Message` and includes ManyToOne relations to user and channel (a message belongs to a `Channel` and to a `User`). Both values are not null. If I exclude the fields `channel` and `user` the serialization succeeded.

In fact the objects `Channel` and `User` have various other connections to `User`, but they are not included in the serialization group. The serialization also fails, if I remove all serialization fields in `Channel` and `User`.

How can I solve this? Or how can I check, where my code fails? If you need further information, I'll add it.

Comment: Check MaxDepth from property

Comment: Both have the annotation `@MaxDepth(1)`.

Comment: increase @MaxDepth()

Comment: I tried to set all `@MaxDepth()` values in `Message`, `Channel` and `User` to 10. The error still occurs.

Comment: then i think problem is with group setup check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437023/symfony2-fosrestbundle-how-to-use-group-with-jmsserializerbundle

Comment: Hmm, no luck with that. I'm using the serializer in my whole app (the app is REST-API based) and this is the first time the error occurs. :(